# Реализация прокси чекера

Tags: api, proxy, service, проверка

Я хочу сделать чекер прокси, который будет определять город и регион прокси по `ip:port`. Был реализован уже подобный чекер и работал до недавних пор, но, видимо, произошло что-то с ним, и он стал выдавать не все города.

Могли бы подсказать сервисы, которые смогут сделать проверку локации прокси?

Может, кто-нибудь подскажет, в каком направлении капать?

Есть ли какие-нибудь внутренние API сервисов для решения данной задачи?